# How to download a link that contains UTF-8 coding with WGET

Tags: download, wget, utf-8

I use wget (Windows) to download webpages. On a site all works well but some webpages return a zero file. Here are commands i execute The first loads well with WGET, the second returns an empty file

This works fine and returns a file containing the source code of the page :

```
wget.exe -O pag.txt --restrict-file-names=nocontrol "http://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/Hasselt/L2137456/Dehaese+%26+Dehaese+Advocatenkantoor/" >nul 2>nul
```

But this one does not work and returns a file pag.txt that is empty

```
wget.exe -O pag.txt --restrict-file-names=nocontrol "http://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/L12587155/L6944363/L%C3%A9gat+%26+Joos+Advocatenkantoor/" >nul 2>nul
```

The problem is that the link contains %C3%A9 which is the UTF-8 code for the character "é"

How can I download the second url ? If you copy the the link directly in the addressbar of Google Chrome, the page loads fine.

Thank you for your help in advance and greetings from Belgium

Comment: Replace "é" with "%E9" as that is what it is in ISO-8859-1 (ECMA Latin1)?

Comment: I replaced %C3%A9 with %E9 in the link, but still I get a pag.txt that is empty so download does not work

Answer (score 0):

In `PowerShell` this command work well for me and download the desired page:

```
wget -O pag.txt "http://www.goudengids.be/bedrijf/L12587155/L6944363/L%C3%A9gat+%26+Joos+Advocatenkantoor/"
```

Comment: in PowerShell ? I call the wget from a Harbour program. This wget line you say that downloaded the page does not work, it results in a pag.txt of 0 (zero) bytes